# How to compare content of an string array to a string

Tags: java, android, if-statement, random, textview

I'm having troubles with an `if` statement to do something if the current string in a `TextView` is "Heads."

This is my current code:

```
 if (myCoin = "Heads") {

                 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                 img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heads);

             }
```

"myCoin" is the name of a string that contains the words "Heads" and "Tails."

```
final String[] myCoin= {"Heads", "Tails"};
```

When a random number is generated, the `TextView` displays one of those words depending on the number. However, I am not able to run the code due to the squiggly red-line under `(myCoin = "Heads")` that reads:

```
Incompatible Types.

Required: Java.Lang.String[]

Found: Java.Lang.String
```

As you can see, my string **DOES** have the square brackets, so I'm wondering if I can even use `myCoin` in an `if` statement.

**SOLVED**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: myCoin is a `final` variable, testing if myCoin[0] is equals to `Heads` will always be true - what are you wanting to do?

Comment: myCoin is an array... and you are trying to see if that array, which you already defined as an array which has heads and tails, is equal to heads?

Comment: You can't compare string and string array. The string is contained in a string array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem a)

`=` is an assignment, you are wanting `.equals`

problem b)

`myCoin` is an array

if you do

```
myCoin[0].equals ("Heads")
```

it will always be true

Answer (score 1):

TRY IT **Best For Me** if(Arrays.asList(myCoin).contains("Heads"))

Answer (score 0):

```
final String[] myCoin= {"Heads", "Tails"};

if (myCoin = "Heads") {
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heads);
 }

//----------------------------------------------------------
```

your variable is array. therefore your code look like this... ff:

```
final String[] myCoin= {"Heads", "Tails"};

int randomNumber = Math.random(10)%2;

if (myCoin[randomNumber].equals("Heads")){ //when you are in string condition symbol must .equals instead '=' .
   ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heads);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

myCoin is an array, so it could not be equal to a String.

You should use

```
if myCoin[random].equals("Heads") {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two objects you have to use "==".

== is the equivalent of "Equals to" and = is the equivalent of "Set equal to"

```
//This checks if A is equal to one
if (A == 1){  
     //This sets A equal to one
     A = 1;
}
```

Also, you are trying to check the entire array when you put

```
  if (myCoin == "Heads") {
  }
```

You should be checking a String within the array by passing a number into it and then checking if the strings are equal. It is worth noting that when comparing strings you want to use the .equals() method. The code below will check to see if the first item in the array "myCoin" is equivalent to "Heads".

```
 if (myCoin[0].equals("Heads")){
 }
```

There is a very indepth explanation between the differences of == and .equals() method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).